# Is this method of making copy of a linked list correct?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void InsertAtTail(struct node** headref,int val)
{
    struct node *current,*newnode;
    current=*headref;
    newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(current==NULL)
    {
        newnode->data=val;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        *headref=newnode;
        current=*headref;
    }

    else
    {

        while(current->next!=NULL)
        {
            current=current->next;
        }

        newnode->data=val;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        current->next=newnode;
    }
}

struct node* CopyList(struct node* headref)
{
    struct node* newlist=NULL;
    struct node* current;
    current=headref;


    if(current==NULL)
    {
        newlist=current;
    }

    else
    {
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            InsertAtTail(&newlist, current->data);
            current=current->next;
        }

    }
    return (newlist);
}
```

I was going through Stanford's CS101 notes and found code for making a copy of linked list. But it used a pointer to the tail node as well. I have written this code without using that(tail pointer). I am new to linked list. Please tell me if I can proceed this way as well. When I printed the original and copy's addresses, both were different too. I am using c in Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Yes the code works fine. As I have mentioned, when I print to check addresses of the two linked list's nodes(original and the copy), different addresses are displayed for corresponding nodes of the two linked lists.

Comment: well, not using the tail pointer makes your list very slow - the list copy is O(n^2), so even though primarily opinionated answer, I'd say your code is wrong.

Comment: oh yes, i must also take care of the efficacy of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works correct, though shorter:

```
void InsertAtTail(struct node** ref,int val)
{
    while (*ref != NULL) {
        ref = &(*ref)->next;
    }
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=val;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    *ref = newnode;
}
```

And the list copying should be rewritten: N²/2.