# Load Text File Into 2D Array Then Compare Against Literal

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

I have 2D array I want populate then compare to literal

below is compare code, i try different things with no success

```
char** list;

load(list);

if(strcmp(list[0], "aasdf"))
{
    printf("win\n");
}
```

the above segfaults on strcmp

load function

```
void load(char **list)
{
int MAX_NUM_LINES = 1000;

FILE *fp;

list = malloc(MAX_NUM_LINES*sizeof(char*));
fp = fopen("list", "r");

line_ct = 0;
char line[256];
while ( fgets(line, 256, fp) != NULL )
{
   int len = strlen(line);
   list[line_ct] = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(list[line_ct], line);
   line_ct++;

   if(line_ct == MAX_NUM_LINES)
   {
        break;
   }
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

any ideas on why is segfault?

also i try before strcmp

```
printf("Line: %s\n", *list[0]);
```

it segfault to

Comment: `malloc(len * sizeof(char));` -> `malloc(len + 1);` (need extra char for string terminator).

Comment: @RomanianStrife I was editing my answer when you accepted it, read it again for more ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you come back from *load* the var *list* is not set, so when you do

```
 if(strcmp(list[0], "aasdf"))
```

you have an undefined behavior using *list* (typically a crash)

---

The first solution is use an output var

you need to change

> ```
> load(list);
> ```

by

```
load(&list);
```

and you need to change the type of *list* and dereference it in *load*, so :

```
void load(char ***list)
{
  *list = malloc(MAX_NUM_LINES*sizeof(char*));
  ...
  (*list)[line_ct] = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy((*list)[line_ct], line);
```

I also added 1 to *len* to have place for the ending null character.

(edit) The use of a *** is not very common, as suggested by @user3629249 in a remark you can look at [Triple pointers in C: is it a matter of style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488544/triple-pointers-in-c-is-it-a-matter-of-style) reading carefully the answers.

---

The second solution is to return the allocated array :

```
char** list = load();
```

with

```
char ** load()
{
   char **list;
   ...
   return list;
```

also adding 1 to *len* when you allocate each line

---

Out of that if you read more than `MAX_NUM_LINES` lines you write out of the array again with an undefined behavior, and the caller of *load* does not know how much lines you read.

To avoid that you can first initialize *list* with `malloc(0)` then use *realloc* to increase the size of *list* each time you read a line, that allows  to allocate the right size. To indicate the size to the caller you can use an additional output var or to allocate one entry more to place NULL in the last entry (all depends on how you use the read array in the code calling *load*)

Comment: using:  `void load(char ***list)` is a very bad idea.  suggest reading: [three star programmer](http://don.fed.wiki.org/view/three-star-programmer)

Comment: @user3629249 yes and no, but as you can see I also propose to not use that way and return the value which is more practical. Note in my answer I propose first the *** to follow the use of a parameter as the OP, not because I prefer that way ;-) Your link is out of S.O., if you find one equivalent in S.O. I edit my answer to add it ^^

Comment: Since most discussion about three star programmers is (somewhat) negative,  The PC freaks have remove (almost) all the related documents.  Here is a link inside SO: [three star programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488544/triple-pointers-in-c-is-it-a-matter-of-style)

Comment: @user3629249 I didn't found it (that means I did not search enough ^^), as promise I edited my answer to add it