# Dynamic deallocation of a 2D matrix crashing

Tags: c, function, matrix, malloc

I have a function which allocates 2D matrix at the start and a function which deallocates it, which I use at the end.

```
int** CreatMat(int N){
    int i,**T;
    T = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
    if(T!=NULL){
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            T[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
            if(T[i]==NULL){
                printf("\nCreatMat()::Allocation failed at block %d",i);
                for(i=i;i>=0;i--){
                    free(T[i]);
                    T[i]=NULL;
                }
                free(T);
                T=NULL;
                return T;
            }
        }
    }
    return T;
}

//Free a dynamic matrix.
void FreeMat(int** T,int N){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        free(T[i]);
        T[i]=NULL;
    }
    free(T);
    T = NULL;
}
```

Somehow, `FreeMat()` is crashing. any help?

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/EFJg9FDC)

~janky fix code [here](https://pastebin.com/d3k5aXrE)

Comment: And *between* allocating and freeing?

Comment: other functions that edit the ints in those matrices, and prints them, I wanted to keep it short here, I can add them if u want.

Comment: `T = NULL;` is nonsense. The caller will never notice.

Comment: This code is fine.  The problem is in the code you haven't shown us.  Presumably you're stepping on memory you shouldn't, so run your code through valgrind to find the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows the fault (with the runtime input). The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described.

Comment: will [this][1] do? [1]: https://pastebin.com/EFJg9FDC

Comment: Not usually, it makes it uphill for readers. But: in `main()` this `if(Grids_Init(T,S)!=0)` does *not* affect the value of the local variables `S` and `T` which remain uninitialised and you then go on to free these indeterminate pointers. The deployment of a debugger would have revealed this quickly.

Comment: so I need to use `int***`? so I can pass `&S` and `&T`?

Comment: aha, a three-star programmer! *plonk*

Comment: Keep it simple. Use one function to initialise one of them, `return` the pointer and assign it to `S`. Then same for `T`.

Comment: Please don't post answers inside the question. I've done a rollback of changes. If you wish to expand on the posted answers, it's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `main()` this

```
int **T, **S;
if(Grids_Init(T, S) != 0)
```

does not affect the value of the local variables `S` and `T` which remain uninitialised, and you then go on to free these indeterminate pointers.

You can use a function to initialise one of them, return the pointer and assign it to `T`. Then same for `S`.

This is preferable to using the three-star pointers: please see [Triple pointers in C: is it a matter of style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488544/triple-pointers-in-c-is-it-a-matter-of-style) One answer begins with

> Using triple pointers is harming both readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You do not create 2D array only an array of pointers. Make your life easier and locate a real **2D** array. Also, use the correct type for sizes `size_t`

```
void CreatMat(size_t N, int (**array)[N])
{
    *array = malloc(N * sizeof(**array));
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*array)[N];
    CreatMat(1000, &array);

    /* some code */

    free(array);
}
```

See how much easier it is.

Comment: Thank you, this would make things easier, but if we were to define a `array` type how would we define it? also using `sizeof()` and passing an `*******ptr` to it will always return 8bits, I think.

Comment: @YacineMegrah I do not understand `*******ptr`. Your comment makes not too much sense

Comment: I meant that passing any pointer to `sizeof()` will always return 8;

Comment: @YacineMegrah you do not understand what my code does. Test it first, and do not assume anything

Comment: how can I access a `T[i][j]` in `main()` ? is it `array[i][j]`?

Comment: @YacineMegrah yes.

Comment: I used `void PrintMat(int N,int (*array)[N])` then called `PrintMat(7,array)` which prints every `array[i][j]`, could you tell me where is the faulty part in this? cuz it didn't print anything.

Comment: @YacineMegrah I do not see `PrintMat` function in your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow should really add a dropdown code snips or smth, I am going ham on pastebin rn, <a href="https://pastebin.com/RzNR43SP"> this is your code</a>

Comment: @YacineMegrah Soply edit your question - no external links

Comment: I have added another code to question, Is it equal to yours?

Comment: @YacineMegrah Check out [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). If you scroll down to the bottom of the answer, there's an example showing that the level of indirection using this method doesn't get worse than `**`, for example `void arr_alloc (size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int(**aptr)[x][y][z])` would be used for a 3D array.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @0_______

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i,j;
    int (*T)[7];
    //(*T)[7] = malloc(7*sizeof(&(*T))); is wrong
    T = malloc(7*sizeof(*T));
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            printf("%d  ");
        }
    }
    free(T);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might find `T = malloc( sizeof(int[7][7]) );` less confusing and easier to read.

Comment: @Lundin I would love to write that if I could,
 "Is it qual to `(*T)[7] = malloc(7*sizeof(&(*T)));` ?" is my concern.

Comment: no it is wrong!!! if you want 7x7 `T = malloc(7*sizeof(*T));`

Comment: @Lundin it is error-prone. You need to change all sizeofs if you change the definition of `T`. The idea is to use objects not types in sizeof to make your code less error-prone

Comment: `&*` is the same as not using either operator so you end up with `sizeof(T)` rather than `sizeof(*T)` as intended.

Comment: @0___________ As demonstrated by the OP, the `*T` version is equally error prone, or they would have gotten it right. It's subjective coding style which version to use. Obviously one should use named constants instead of magic numbers though. Better yet, wrap all of it in a struct.

Comment: Sorcery! it worked!

Comment: @Lundin , so you suggest `typedef struct {int(*M)[7]} matrix_7; `? and  `typdef matrix int**` for Original iteration?

Comment: @YacineMegrah never hide arrays and pointers behind the typedefs

Comment: @Lundin indeed - first you need to learn what `*` & `&` do. Without it everything is error prone

Comment: @YacineMegrah No I suggested that you would simply wrap the array inside a struct and leave allocation of it as a separate matter. That is `typedef struct { int m[7][7]; } matrix;`. Not very flexible though. But this is heading off-topic.

Comment: Well, my understanding is that : `*` could be used to declare a pointer, or to dereference it (down a step or power) ,  and `&` is used to access the adresse of something (default pointer to that target) .

Comment: `*` can be used for dereferencing and `&` for referencing, so they take each other out. The C standard explicitly states that this is what happens when you use `&*`.

Answer (score 0):

- representing a matrix as an array of pointers is suboptimal: it wastes memory and time, and the locality of reference will be worse
- once you *think* you need more than a *double pointer*, you should rethink your data: use some structure to represent the matrix.

A simple example:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrix {
        unsigned nrow;
        unsigned ncol;
        // int flags;
        double *data;
        };

/*****************************************************************/
static size_t nrc2idx(unsigned ncol, unsigned irow, unsigned icol)
{
return (irow*ncol) + icol;
}

struct matrix *matrix_new(unsigned nrow, unsigned ncol)
{
struct matrix *mp;

mp = malloc (sizeof *mp);
if (!mp) return mp;
mp->data = malloc (sizeof *mp->data * nrow * ncol);
if ( !mp->data) {
        free (mp);
        return NULL;
        }
mp->nrow = nrow;
mp->ncol = ncol;

return mp;
}
```

---

Now, how hard is it to multiply two matrices, using this kind of struct?
Example code:

---

```
struct matrix *matrix_mult(struct matrix *left, struct matrix *right)
{
struct matrix *result;
unsigned ii,jj;

if (!left || !right) return NULL;
if (left->ncol != right->nrow) return NULL;

result = matrix_new(left->nrow, right->ncol);
if (!result) return NULL;

for (ii=0; ii < result->nrow; ii++) {
        for (jj=0; jj < result->ncol; jj++) {
                size_t uu;
                unsigned kk;
                double sum ;
                sum = 0.0;
                for (kk=0; kk < left->ncol; kk++) {
                        size_t aa, bb;
                        aa = nrc2idx(left->ncol, ii, kk);
                        bb = nrc2idx(right->ncol, kk, jj);
                        sum += left->data[aa] * right->data[bb];
                        }
                uu = nrc2idx(result->ncol, ii, jj);
                result->data[uu] = sum;
                }
        }
return result;
}
```

Comment: it is suboptimal as well. Use proper types for sizes (`size_t`) not unsigned. Having too many returns is error prone (rather use positive checks instead negative)

Comment: If going down this route you should use flexible array members instead. Otherwise you haven't really solved the program with fragmented malloc calls and pointless levels of indirection.

Comment: I said it was a simplified example. It is only intended to show the concept of "encapsulation" (BTW: IMHO flexible array members are too hard for the OP, since he is still struggeling with pointers and arrays)

Comment: I see the point you're making , However, am trying to reserve the `T[i][j]` format for my project , and also lack the skill to maintain integrity for this code when I implement it, as this OP is only a Library for SDL2_project.