# How to free a 2D array allocated on N+1 mallocs ? In C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, malloc, free

I have an exercise which asks me to free a 2D array, which was allocated with mallocs. I've already searched on stack and many websites but I'm still stuck.

I have to complete a function and then free the 2D array in arg. and make it to NULL.

```
void FreeMatrix(int*** ptab, int N){
   /// to complete
}
```

I already tried **this** but it doesnt work, and there is also 2 pictures that my teacher handed me to "help me" but I don't really understand it either.

```
for (int i = 0; i<N;i++){
   free(ptab[i]);
}
free(ptab);
```

=> The program crashes

Thanks for your help in advance :(
[The first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwntC.jpg)
[The second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzPgr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a 3 star pointer, you need an extra dereference in your function:

```c
void FreeMatrix(int*** ptab, int N)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        // *ptab is an int** type, and that makes (*ptab)[i] an
        // int* type. Presumably, you've malloced N int* types, so
        // free each of those
        free((*ptab)[i]);
    }

    // now free the initial int** allocation
    free(*ptab);
    // and set it to NULL per your requirements
    *ptab= NULL;
}
```

[Working example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ecbfaae7T)

Note that 3-star pointers are [generally considered bad design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488544/triple-pointers-in-c-is-it-a-matter-of-style)